# "Plan for" vs. "Plan around"

Tags: meaning, differences

What are the differences between each?

1. Someone is planning *for* another element's presence.
2. Someone is planning *around* another element's presence.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that, if somebody was planning *around* something, it would be more important to the person doing the planning than if it was planning *for* that same something.

Answer (score 1):

"Planning for" gives the impression that the reason for planning an event is for the sake of the other party/individual/event/element. "Planning around" is as if plans for the other party/individual/event/element already exist, and planning is being done for other things with consideration to these preexisting plans involving that party/individual/event/element.

Answer (score 1):

Planning for means fixing a schedule for an event. Planning around means fixing another things' schedule for the event. Hope the below examples help.

1. "I am planning for Sasha's birthday tomorrow." This means that birthday plan is not set yet and I am planning all the events including buying gifts, cake and cutting of the cake.
2. "I am planning more events around Sasha's birthday event." This means I am planning extra things like shopping, movie, dinner for before and after cake cutting.

Comment: Another meaning of "planning around" is planning to accommodate a conflicting requirement or issue.  "Sasha's birthday party is tomorrow and I need to plan around rain expected at lunchtime."